# Not fire queued jobs with no channels?

Tags: php, laravel, pusher

Is there any way to suppress queued jobs from firing off a broadcast event when the channel is empty? Basically what I am noticing is that while no socket pushes will go off if `broadcastOn` returns `[]` it will still make a queued job. Is there any way to have queued jobs only get created when `broadcastOn` returns an array with at least one element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems in Laravel 5.4 you can now add a new method on events, `broadcastWhen`. All that needs to be done:

```
public function broadcastOn() {
    return [];
}

public function broadcastWith() {
   return count($this->broadcastOn()) > 0;
}
```

You can read more about how `broadcastWhen` is handled in the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php#L251).

> Check if event should be broadcasted by condition.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do a little manual subclassing to make this work. The queued job is created in the `broadcastEvent` method of `Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher`.

```
protected function broadcastEvent($event)
{
    if ($this->queueResolver) {
        $connection = $event instanceof ShouldBroadcastNow ? 'sync' : null;

        $queue = method_exists($event, 'onQueue') ? $event->onQueue() : null;

        $this->resolveQueue()->connection($connection)->pushOn($queue, 'Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent', [
            'event' => serialize(clone $event),
        ]);
    }
}
```

You can add a check here to only push the job onto the queue if `$event->broadcastOn` returns an array with at least one element.

Once subclassed, you will need to use the new dispatcher to fire the events. You can create a new service provider for this and bind it to the container. I'm not sure if you can overwrite the existing `events` instance created in `Illuminate\Events\EventServiceProvider`, but you can definitely create a new one.

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->singleton('events-custom', function ($app) {
        return (new App\Provides\CustomDispatcher($app))->setQueueResolver(function () use ($app) {
            return $app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\Factory');
        });
    });
}
```

If you are using the Events facade, be sure to also update your config file to point to a new Facade that returns the key to your new CustomDispatcher. Unfortunately, the `events()` helper function will still return the original Dispatcher. I don't believe that can be overwritten. If you can somehow overwrite the existing `events` key set by `Illuminate\Events\EventServiceProvider` though, then you're all set.